# Are my standard Ubuntu open network ports at risk???

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu (I installed it just 4 days ago) and want to know something about network ports: which port is opened or closed?

I read many answers about this field, but I am unable to understand how to identify ports (opened or closed). When I run this command `sudo netstat -ntlup` I get the following output:

[image: screenshot]

Could you tell me, which port is open or at risk? How to close open ports using firewall rules?

Comment: Nothing seems out of order with the ports that are open in your list. By default, no ports are opened in Linux unless a service specifically opens them. Unless you have installed a firewall like `ufw`, ports are typically managed through `iptables` for which you can read `man iptables` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer depends on what your definition of "open ports" are:

1. if you mean by "open ports", the ports that are *open on your internal LAN*, then the `netstat` command is very useful and looking at the output of your command, the open ports are *absolutely normal* for a computer that:

   - uses DNS
   - uses DHCP
   - has a printer defined ans wants to share it.
2. if you mean by "open ports", the ports that are *visible to the Internet*, then the `netstat` command is *not very useful* and there are tons of sites out there that can test your Internet connectivity.  [Here's just one of the oldest and best](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)

Comment: Thank you guys,and yes I want to know about the ports that are visible to the internet.Again thank you both of you.

Comment: If you want to know as much about networking as me, [buy this book](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469)